# Cannot link executable NDK ffmpeg - Android 7 Nougat

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-7.0-nougat

I am using ffmpeg in my project and it was working fine until I tried it on Android 7.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand);
Map<String, String> env = builder.environment();
env.put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/data/data/pakage:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
```

When I read the output it return me the following error:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/pakage/ffmpeg": /data/data/pakage/ffmpeg: has text relocations
```

Used targeting api 23 as well as 22, still not working.
Is it related to NDK Apps Linking?
How can I fix this?

Comment: did you found any solution for it ?

Comment: Yes, used pre compiled library @AbhishekB

Comment: i tried too, can you share the link, thanks

Comment: Follow this link https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java